# Efficient pythonic way to multiply elements(which are tuple) of each row represented in np.array structure

Tags: python, tuples, numpy-ndarray

The data is represented as below. Here the data has 3 columns(as an example) but in general, the data will have more columns

```
data_set = np.array([[1, (1, 2.5), (2, 3)], [2, (2, 5.7), (1.6, 4.1)], [3, (3, 7.3), (5, 6)], [4, (6, 9.1), (1.6, 2.5)]])

[[1 (1, 2.5) (2, 3)]
 [2 (2, 5.7) (1.6, 4.1)]
 [3 (3, 7.3) (5, 6)]
 [4 (6, 9.1) (1.6, 2.5)]]
```

Discarding the first column I want to multiply the rest of the elements per row. Here the values in the columns(except the first one) are represented as tuples. So to multiply I have to unpack the tuple first and then subtract(Need to do this for all the columns) and then multiply. So for example, If I consider the first row I should get the below answers

```
Column 1 row 1 -> 2.5 - 1 = 1.5 
Column 2 row 1 -> 3   - 2 = 1 
1.5*1 = 1.5
```

and then store the value in a dictionary where

```
Key = 1(the value of Column 0 row 1) and Value = 1.5(the product)
```

I can do it in a basic way but was wondering is there any efficient pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Just for house-keeping: you've updated your question to use the `np.array` type, but the question title still mentions `ndarray`, perhaps you could update that to read `np.array` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a pythonic and straightforward solution:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
      [[1, (1, 2.5), (2, 3)],
       [2, (2, 5.7), (1.6, 4.1)],
       [3, (3, 7.3), (5, 6)],
       [4, (6, 9.1), (1.6, 2.5)]]
)

result = {a: (c - b) * (e - d) for a, (b, c), (d, e) in data}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{1: 1.5, 2: 9.249999999999998, 3: 4.3, 4: 2.7899999999999996}
```

It's hard to beat the performance of a comprehension like this to construct a dictionary, if that's the data format you need.

You might be able to construct something faster using purely `numpy` and a numpy array as the output format, but even for moderately sized inputs, I'd probably favour this very readable solution.

Note that, if the number of tuples on a row is variable (or just large), I'd solve it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

data = np.array(
      [[1, (1, 2.5), (2, 3)],
       [2, (2, 5.7)],
       [3, (3, 7.3), (5, 6), (6, 1), (.5, 1)],
       [4, (6, 9.1), (1.6, 2.5)]]
)

result = {row[0]: reduce(lambda acc, t: acc * (t[1] - t[0]), row[1:], 1) for row in data}

print(result)
```

Readability suffers a bit, but now it will work for any number of tuple columns, even if the number of columns isn't the same for every row.

Another minor update - since Python 3.8, there is a standard function for multiplication of all elements of an iterable, so you could use that instead of `.reduce()` in this case:

```
import numpy as np
from math import prod

data = np.array(
      [[1, (1, 2.5), (2, 3)],
       [2, (2, 5.7)],
       [3, (3, 7.3), (5, 6), (6, 1), (.5, 1)],
       [4, (6, 9.1), (1.6, 2.5)]]
)

result = {row[0]: prod(y - x for x, y in row[1:]) for row in data}

print(result)
```

As Python evolves, there's always a "more Pythonic" approach.

Comment: The output is in the format I want. I might have a column size around 60-80. How to incorporate that into the code

Comment: I've updated the code with a more generic example, that should work for many columns as well.